# Current experimental evidence of lepton flavour violation other than neutrino oscillation

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, large-hadron-collider, beyond-the-standard-model, leptons

Is *Lepton Flavour Violation* (LFV) experimentally established in processes other than neutrino oscillation? [This answer by Luboš Motl](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/191038/44126) points out that

> Interestingly, CMS has detected a 2.5 sigma excess of Higgs bosons that seemingly decay to
>   $$ h \to \mu^\pm \tau^\mp $$
>   This is an example of a process that would violate the flavor numbers. A muon is created with an anti-tau, or vice versa. Note that this process is compatible with the charge (and energy, momentum etc.) conservation laws, the truly important ones. But it changes $L_\mu$ and $L_\tau $ by $\pm 1$ and $\mp 1$, respectively.

1. Can it taken as the experimental evidence for lepton flavour violation independent from neutrino oscillation?
2. Did the LHC observe other signatures for LFV? If yes, what is the confidence level of the observations?

Comment: 1. Not at this significance. 2. No, but there are some hints of violation of lepton universality.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no :)

(At least thus far.)